# Table plotted using Pylot is not clear

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

I've a csv file and we are required to use pyplot.table method to display a table. I tried the following approach

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
data=data[:10]


cell_text=data.values.tolist()
colu_lables=data.columns.tolist()


plt.table(cellText=cell_text,
                     colLabels=colu_lables,loc='center',fontsize=30.0)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

which gives me a table but the issue is that values are unclear and unreadable. How to fix this ? Or is there is any better way to do it please inform me I am new to python. Thanks in advance
Edit:
[This is how it looks like as of now I tried the font-size property but it isnt working for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG4Rd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your data would look like but your could just use to set the `font` of all items to the font specified by the `kwargs` object, `font`.

you could also use the `rcParams update` method to do this.

As i don't have any data i took `matplotlib` [example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/table_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-misc-table-demo-py).

**Output Image:** small fonts, may be same as your data plot.

[image]

not let's use `rcParams update` method to increase the font of all elements in the `figure`. Just after importing all the library copy below code.

```py
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22}) # increase font to all element
```

This will increase the size of the font in the table as well.

**Output Image:** with bigger fonts,

[image]